# Average steps it takes to fill a (n-sized 1-D) array choosing n random numbers each time

Tags: probability, statistics

I found that the average of steps it takes to fill a (n-sized 1-D) array seems to be *approximately* $log(n) + 1$. ($log$ base $e$).

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCu1A.png) shows the plotted data along with the logarithmic fit.
[image]

I'm not sure if it's clear, so here is an example. 
Suppose we have a 10-sized array $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$.

I built an algorithm to do the following:

1. Choose 10 random elements from the original array (e.g, $[2,2,3,0,5,5,5,7,1,1]$)
2. Create a new array using only the unique elements that I got. In this case $[0,1,2,3,5,7]$.
3. Again choose randomly 10 elements and add unique values to new array.
4. Count how many times it was necessary to add 10 elements until the new array was exactly equal to the original one.
5. Repeat this process many times and take the average.

In Python:

```
def trials(repeat, size):
    array, count = np.arange(size), 0
    for i in range(repeat):
        new_array = []
        while True:
            count += 1
            new_array.extend(set(choices(array, k = size)).difference(new_array))
```

if len(new_array) == size:
            break
return count/repeat

At least for me this is a curious fact that even for large arrays the number of steps don't grow as much. My question is: this must be a known fact. I've lookup but found little related to that. Does anyone knows what's happening here ?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem
The same problem arises in hashing.

Comment: Thank you, @lightxbulb. The definition of the problem seems to be the same, indeed. But I'm not entirely convinced because the expected number of tries grows as $O(n\log n)$ instead of $O(\log n)$ that I got. Perhaps the Coupon Collector's Problem is a generalization of this question, but that's not clear to me.

Comment: I believe that it is your implementation or reasoning about the results. Here's something I coded for you: https://ideone.com/5Vgi10 as expected it produces a result close to $n\log n$. What I assume the issue in your case is, is that you are picking 10 at a time, spoiling the constant, so even if it's still $O(n \log n)$, it just has a constant such that for arrays of size of only $500$ you get a misleading result (remember big-O notation is regarding the asymptotic behaviour). @Alvaro

Comment: If you are filling an array with for example $200$ locations, then it is going to take you at least $200$ attempts and probably many more because of duplicates.  So your figure around $6$ looks peculiar, but would look plausible if you multiplied it by $200$

Comment: @lightxbulb Yeah, I think that's possible. So in my case the expected result would be something in order of $\frac{n \log n}{n}$.

Comment: I appreciate your comments on this questions!

Comment: @Alvaro Obviously if you need about $n \log n$ tries to fill an array with $n$ elements, then if you draw $m$ in one step that's the same as making $m$ steps and putting 1 element in (the original formulation of the coupon collector problem). So yes you would get $\frac{Cn\log n}{m}$ if you put in $m$ elements per step. Note that if $m$ is a constant (does not depend on $n$) then the time is still $O(n\log n)$ just the constant is smaller (but for large enough $n$ you will see it converge to $n \log n$).

Comment: I've got it now. Thanks!